# Peculiar Nested radicals, cosine values, Jacobsthal-Lucas numbers

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, integers, nested-radicals

Let us consider half angle formula for equilateral triangle in unit circle with initial angle as $\frac{\pi}{3}$

$2\cos\frac{\pi}{6} = \sqrt{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}} = \sqrt{2+1}$

Further half angle when iterated we will get the results as follows

$2\cos\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^2} = \sqrt{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^1}} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+1}}}$

$2\cos\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^3} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^1}}} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+1}}}$

**The pattern is clear and obvious and converges to 2 when it is infinite nested radical**

> Let us imagine negative signs in the nested radicals and cosine angles

$\sqrt{3} = 2\cos\frac{\pi}{6}$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt3} = 2\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^2} = 2\cos\frac{5\pi}{3\cdot2^2}$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}} = 2\sin\frac{5\pi}{3\cdot2^3} = 2\cos\frac{7\pi}{3\cdot2^3}$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}} = 2\sin\frac{7\pi}{3\cdot2^4} = 2\cos\frac{17\pi}{3\cdot2^4}$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}}} = 2\sin\frac{17\pi}{3\cdot2^5} = 2\cos\frac{31\pi}{3\cdot2^5}$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}}}} = 2\sin\frac{31\pi}{3\cdot2^6} = 2\cos\frac{65\pi}{3\cdot2^6}$

It is interesting to note that, the above pattern is amazing in number pattern in numerator as follows

$5 = 2^2+1$; $7 = 2^3-1$; $17 = 2^4+1$; $31 = 2^6+1$; $65 = 2^2+1$; $127 = 2^7-1$;...

> This corresponds to Jacobsthal-Lucas numbers [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C7%2C17%2C31%2C65&language=english&go=Search).
> For $n$ number of $-$ signs cosine angle can be derived as follows

$$2\cos(\frac{2^{n+1}-(-1)^n}{3\cdot2^{n+1}})\pi$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\cos(\frac{2^{n+1}-(-1)^n}{3\cdot2^{n+1}})\pi = 2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}=1 $$

Even though it is very easy to derive the numerator by above method, this sequence of nested radical also expresses the geometric progression in a different way. (I hope if I continue here some of you may curse for long posts. So I'm leaving to work out yourself)

**This particular finite to infinite nested radical is peculiar and notorious in the sense that it starts with $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and when extended to infinity ends with $\frac{\pi}{3}$ - (circular)**

**Questions:**

**1. Please explain about Jacobsthal-Lucas numbers and their significance**

(In previous post I was easily able to represent cyclic infinite or finite nested square roots of 2 respectively as $cin\sqrt2$ or $n\sqrt2$ as they involved only number 2. But here we get another number ($\sqrt3$ in this case)  at the right extreme of radicals)

**2. How can we name above nested radical simply? Please suggest**

Comment: $31 = 2^5-1, 65 = 2^6+1$

Comment: you might enjoy https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tafeln_complexer_Primzahlen/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false   which does prime denominators up to 97, then various composite denominators.